# Avoid TS2571 when using $refs inside a template

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-tsc

Assuming SomeComp is a custom component exposing a function `open`, in a template I can do this:

```xml
    <button @click="$refs.someComp.open()">Open</button>
    <SomeComp ref="someComp" />
```

However when running type check, `vue-tsc` will fail with

> TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'

coplaining about the someComp ref.
How do I resolve this?
Can the type somehow be inferred or Do I have to declare it again?
In a `ref<>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to define is as a ref.

In `script setup` this would look like

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  import {ref} from 'vue'
  let someComp = ref<SomeComp>();
</script>
<template>
    <button @click="someComp.open()">Open</button>
    <SomeComp ref="someComp" />
</template>
```

Don't use $refs as it's untyped iirc